# Apache 2.4 PHP 7.4 Include and Require don't include PHP files, but others files types are correctly included

Tags: php, apache-2.4, synology

I have a weird and quite difficult to understand problem

I have a micro PHP app that has index.php ad a couple of others files *.php that are included in the index.php, let's call the two to be included files include1.php and include2.php

Well, if I try to include include1.php and include2.php, they are NOT included and you get the PHP exception files not present in such path

But, listen listen, if I rename the two files include1.txt and include2.txt THEY ARE INCLUDED!!!

So thank you if you save me from this headache

Please note , the system is basically linux, but the linux of a Synology NAS with the webstation enabled and all the rest ... and since on the same NAS, I have installed PHPMyAdmin and it does work ... I'm pretty sure PHP does work correctly

I suspect about some security configuration issue or permission issue

Thank you for hints and tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having enabled all the available kinds of errors reporting,

I ended up to notice a MariaDB error

This for some reason was making consequences for the following includes.

Also note that on Synology, the connection string for MariaDB **won't work with** `localhost`, use `127.0.0.1` instead